# Shouldn't tie be called untie?

Tags: c++, stl

```
int rno; string name; int marks;
tuple <int, string, int> x=make_tuple(1, "anukul", 100);
tie(rno, name, marks)=x;
```

This piece of code assigns the values in tuple x to the variables.
In a way, it unpacks the tuple x.

So why is the function called 'tie'?
What does it tie?

cplusplus states that it "Ties arguments to tuple elements".
But a change in tuple elements does not reflect in the variables.

Comment: IMHO tie is the proper name. It ties `rno` to `x[0]`.

Comment: But a change in tuple elements does not reflect in the variables. If they indeed were 'tied' to each other, it would not have been so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie)

> Creates a tuple of *lvalue references* to its arguments [...]

so in addition to using it to "unpack" a tuple into variables as you did, you can also use it as follows

```
int rno = 10; string name; int marks;
tuple <int&, string&, int&> x = tie(rno, name, marks);
get<0>(x) = 42;
cout << rno; // 42
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3eed01b615aefca)</kbd>

I wouldn't deem the code above to be 'unpacking' anything, but rather *tying* the variables together with a tuple of lvalue references.

As [utnapistim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186997/utnapistim) suggested (and  [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) shows in the sample code) another possible use unrelated from 'unpacking' is in memberwise comparisons

```
struct comparable { 
  int a, b; 
  bool operator==(const comparable& x) { 
    return std::tie(a, b) == std::tie(x.a, x,b); 
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I had not seen this usage before. Explains the name 'tie' well.

Comment: Another common use is to shorten memberwise comparisons: `struct comparable { int a, b; bool operator==(const comparable& x) { return std::tie(a, b) == std::tie(x.a, x,b); }};` (performs equality comparison value by value, starting with index zero).

Comment: @utnapistim I'll edit it in for completeness' sake. Thanks.

Comment: Is the real reason it is called tie because I'm tying `rno`, `name` and `marks` in the statement in my question to assign values of `x` to them (as suggested in @Angew's answer) or because `rno`, `name` and `marks` can be tied into a tuple (as you showed in the answer)?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan you're tying the variables together in a tuple of lvalue references in both cases

Answer (score 7):

It *ties* the names `rho`, `name`, and `marks` *in the assignment statement* so that they behave like a tuple (can be assigned to as a single entity). It refers to what it does (tie several entities into a tuple), not what you do with the result (usually unpack another tuple).

Don't forget what `std::tie` actually returns—a tuple. So you *tie* the variables together into a temporary tuple, and then assign `x` into that temporary tuple. Since the temporary tuple is a tuple of *references,* the assignment writes through to the variables which were *tied* into that temporary tuple.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more? "(can be assigned to as a single entity)" and "tie several entities into a tuple". The variables still remain variables, they aren't parts of a tuple...

Comment: `tie( rno, name, marks )` "ties" the variables together, or you could not assign the *tuple* `x` to them.

Comment: `tuple <int&, string&, int&> x = tie(rno, name, marks);` right?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan Yes, that's what it will give you.

Answer (score 3):

No.

While you have a reasonable argument that you are untying `x`, you are not operating on `x` at the place where you've written `std::tie`.

You are instead operating on `rno`, `name` and `marks`, which *are* being tied together for the assignment.